# drawing points using PlotLab in c#

Tags: c#, .net, plotlab

I'm using PlotLab and SignalLab in my Project.Now I want to plot single points on scope but I cant.The problem is plotLab connects poits together by lines but I want just plot pints.Points Are xy points and I shold use plotLab or sigalLab.How I can do this?

here is my code:

```
            RF_Azimuth.Channels[0].Data.AddXYPoint(freq[iCounter], az[iCounter]);
```

or

```
            RF_Elevation.Channels[0].Data.AddXYData(freq, elv);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing scope channel Mode to "Point" in scope property wizard.